# Summing map values per each key

Tags: java

I have the following maps:

```
{21=0, 22=2, 11=0, 12=0}
{21=3, 22=0, 11=6, 12=3}
{21=6, 22=0, 11=7, 12=0}
{21=5, 22=7, 11=9, 12=1}
```

The following code returns these maps:

```
for (Chrom t: obj.getChroms) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> result = t.getExecutionCount();
}
```

The method `getExecutionCount()` returns a single map. For the example I have given above, I have four chroms where each chrom will returns a single map.

I would like to sum the values of each key seperately so that the final result will be:

```
21 = 14
22 = 9
11 = 22
12 = 4
```

Is it possible to use stream to do that? If not, how can I do that?

Comment: It is possible to do that using streams

Comment: What structure do your maps have? Is it `Map<Integer, Integer>`?

Comment: @deHaar Yes, it is `Map<Integer, Integer>`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer How to do that please?

Comment: You can use stream with map and reduce

Comment: `Map<Integer, Integer>` map can't hold `21=0` and `21=3` at the same time. Map represents key-value pairs where key must be unique. Maybe you meant `Map<Integer,List<Integer>>`?

Comment: It is not a single map, but multiple maps. So first you need to make a single collection from them

Comment: @Pshemo I will edit the question in order to explain how I get these maps

Comment: Stream.of(map1.entrySet(), map2.entrySet(), map3.entrySet())
.flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)));

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
    List<Map<Integer, Integer>> maps;

    Map<Integer, Integer> result = maps.stream()
            .map(Map::entrySet)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create Stream of maps and the use `flatMap`,

```
Stream.of(map1, map2, map3)
      .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet()
                     .stream())
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                   Map.Entry::getKey,
                   Collectors.summingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)
               )
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible using `Stream`. It should work (I can't compile right now unfortunately)

```
Map<Integer, Integer> result = Stream.of(map1, map2, map3, map4)
                                     .map(Map::entrySet)
                                     .flatMap(Set::stream)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                                  Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                  Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                  Integer::sum)
                                     );
```

A little explanation

- Stream over all your `Map`s
- Make a unique `Stream` of all entries contained inside of your `Map`s
- Group every by key
- For the collisions, use `Integer::sum` which will reduce both values for the same key